# JTextArea didn't show all the word

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have GridgabLayout JPanel. I put 4 components, 3 JLabels and 1 JTextArea inside it. the last row is JTextArea component. This GridegabLayout panel is added to the another JPanelfor.  The text in JTextArea has problem as bellows:

```
1. Text in JTextArea cannot show it all.
2. If there are too many word, the first two row of labels cannot see.
```

[image]

On the right hand side of the picture, I changed the text to many words. The first two rows are gone.

there is my code for GridgeabLayout JPanel:
    package PDFAnnotationPackage;

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;



public class DivCommentJPane extends JPanel  {

private BeanPanel thisBean;
private CommentItem thisComment; 
private String pageErrorPrefix="Error On DivCommentJPane.java : "; 
private PDFNotes bean;  
private GridBagConstraints c;


public DivCommentJPane(CommentItem comment ,BeanPanel bean ){

    //thisBean=bean;
    super();        
    thisComment=comment;
    thisBean=test;
    setting();



}

public void setting(){
    try{
    bean=new PDFNotesBean();
    this.setLayout( new GridBagLayout());       
    c = new GridBagConstraints();
    c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    c.weightx = 1.0;  // **** comment this line out to see effect ****
    c.weighty = 1.0;  // **** comment this line out to see effect ****




    buildTopJPane();
    setVisible(true);   
    }catch(Exception  err){
           Utility.DisplayErrorMsg(pageErrorPrefix+ err.getMessage().toString());
       }
}

private JLabel setAttonIconCreator(){
    Icon icon=getAnotIcon();
    JLabel lblAnottIcon=new JLabel(thisComment.creator, icon, JLabel.CENTER);   
    return lblAnottIcon;
}



private JLabel setDeleteIcon(){

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Delete.gif"));
    JLabel lblDeleteIcon=new JLabel("", icon, JLabel.CENTER);   

    lblDeleteIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()  
    {  
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e)  
        {  

             thisBean.annotRemove(thisComment.annotation, thisComment.pageNum);             


        }  
    }); 
    return lblDeleteIcon;

}
private JLabel setPageDateLabel(){
    JLabel lblDate=new JLabel(thisComment.toString());
    return lblDate;
}

/*private JTextPane setContent(){

    JTextPane pane = new JTextPane();
    pane.setText(thisComment.content);
    pane.setEditable(false);



    return pane;

}*/

/*private JTextArea setContent(){
    JTextArea t=new JTextArea();
    t.setText(thisComment.content);
    t.setLineWrap(true);
    t.setEditable(false);
    return t;

}*/

//modified the code like to use JScrollPane
private JScrollPane setContent(){

    JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane();   
    scroll.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 250));
    JTextArea t=new JTextArea(3,120);
    t.setText(thisComment.content);
    t.setLineWrap(true);
    t.setEditable(false);
    scroll.getViewport().add(t);
    return scroll;

}

private  void buildTopJPane(){
    JPanel lnFirst=new JPanel();
    try{


        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;       
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;           
        this.add(setAttonIconCreator(), c);


        c.gridx = 5;
        c.gridy = 0;           
        this.add(setDeleteIcon(),c);

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=1;
        c.gridwidth=4;
        this.add(setPageDateLabel(), c);

        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=2;
        c.gridwidth=4;             
        this.add(setContent(), c);






    } catch(Exception  err){
           Utility.DisplayErrorMsg(pageErrorPrefix+ err.getMessage().toString());
       }


}
@SuppressWarnings("finally")
private SafeIcon getAnotIcon(){
    SafeIcon  antIcon=null;
    try{
     switch (thisComment.type.toLowerCase()){
     case "underline":
         antIcon= new SafeIcon( bean.getAnnotToolbar().getjbTextUnderline().getIcon());
         break;
     case "squiggly":
         antIcon=new SafeIcon(bean.getjbTextSquiggly().getIcon());
         break;
     case "highlight":
         antIcon=new SafeIcon(bean.getjbHighlight().getIcon());
         break;
     case "note":
         antIcon=new SafeIcon(bean.getAnnotToolbar().getjbNote().getIcon());
     default:
         antIcon=new SafeIcon((Icon) ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("SquigglyIcon.gif")));
         return antIcon;
     }
    }catch(IOException  err){
           Utility.DisplayErrorMsg(pageErrorPrefix+ err.getMessage().toString());


       }finally{return antIcon;}



}
```

}

This is the screenshot after adding the JTextArea in JScrollPane.

[image]

Comment: Consider adding the `JTextArea` to a `JScrollPane`

Comment: and create the JTextArea using `new JTextArea(3, 120)` to give the text area a preferred size for the specified rows/columns.

Comment: @camickr, I don't know the total word to display. It is get from other source and I could not limit how many word the user can input

Comment: @user819774, that is fine scrollbars will appear when required. The idea is to provide a default size for the text area the is reasonable to handle the majority of the text without making the text area too big.

Comment: After adding the size of the JTextArea(3,120), I added the JTextArea into the JScrollPane. But the JtextArea only show 1 character with scroll bar. private JScrollPane setContent(){
   
  JScrollPane scroll=new JScrollPane(); 
  JTextArea t=new JTextArea(3,120);
  t.setText(thisComment.content);
  t.setLineWrap(true);
  t.setEditable(false);
  scroll.getViewport().add(t);
  return scroll;
  
 }

Comment: @camickr Also this is the code I added the JScrollPane into the JPanel.c.gridx=0;
            c.gridy=2;
            c.gridwidth=4;         
            this.add(setContent(), c);

Comment: Post a proper `SSCCE`.

Comment: @camickr I updated the code on private JScrollPane setContent function and added the screenshot. Hope you can help me out. Thanks.

Comment: You still haven't posted a `SSCCE` that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @camickr, I think the screen shot show my problem. After adding the scrollPaae in JtextArea. It only show one character. You may look at setContent function. thank.s

Comment: The only suggestion I have is too use a number smaller than 120. A GridBagLayout will use the minimum size of the component if it can't display the component at its preferred size. The default minimum size is very small so you only see the dots. If that doesn't help then post a proper `SSCCE`.